# Clean private data (passwords, ftp, database) before zipping my site and SQL and give it to other person

Tags: migration, private

I want to clean all the private data related with WordPress before sending it to another person. I will zip the folders and then export the sql.

Is there a tutorial with the things that I should check?

Comment: it's simple, you have to check completely all the files because plugins can store private datas everywhere in files or in the DB

Comment: Do you want to clean user_passwords too?

Comment: Export the SQL to a local copy and delete the tables using phpmyadmin? Then re-export as SQL dump. You may want to keep hold of an admin account though...